# Can a dictionary be used to make a graphic rune with matplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

You need your help to solve this problem:

I have a csv file that has a lot of lists in those lists, there are 2 I'm going to focus on:

Gender (which is sex): has all men and women
`Genero = ["Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"]`

Body: that has all the physical aspects.
`Cuerpo =[thin, fat, muscular, thin, thin, normal]`

The problem is that I want to make a diagram showing how many women and men are thin, ex:[image]

and I want to do it with dictionaries that when iterating it calculates how many women and men are thin but I have a problem I get false in the key when I should put women

```
def Grafico (Doc):
    Datos = [s.Genero == "Female" and "Male" for s in Doc if s.Cuerpo == "thin"]
    CC = {Ca: Datos.count(Ca) * 100 / 1000 for Ca in Datos if Ca != ""}

    return CC
```

```
false(524) Male(456)
```

The second error is based on the fact that when I want to make the diagram, it doesn't let me and I don't know what to do.

```
def Grafico (Doc):
    Datos = [s.Genero == "Female" and "Male" for s in Doc if s.Cuerpo == "thin"]
    CC = {Ca: Datos.count(Ca) * 100 / 1000 for Ca in Datos if Ca != ""}
    plt.bar(CC.keys(), CC.values())
    plt.xlabel('SEXO DE LOS DESAPARECIDOS')
    plt.xlabel('Tipo_de_sangre de sangre')
    plt.title('CUANTAS PERSONAS TIENEN ')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.show()
    return
```

I hope your help
thanks for seeing my post

[image]

Comment: I don't think `s.Genero == "Female" and "Male" ` does what you think it does.  Try writing it as a loop and see the values in the debugger.  And don't post images of code, or of error messages.  Instead, put them in your question, formatted properly.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
    Datos = [s.Genero == "Female" and "Male" for s in Doc if s.Cuerpo == "thin"]
```

is parsed as `(s.Genero == "Female") and "Male"`, and since the string "Male" is always true, the expression will always be true.

If those are your only two genders, then why are you checking them?  Just do this:

```
    Datos = [s for s in Doc if s.Cuerpo == "thin"]
```

If you reall do want to check for both sexes, you can do

```
    Datos = [s.Genero in ("Female","Male") for s in Doc if s.Cuerpo == "thin"]
```

but it seems pointless if every record is one or the other.